# How can I download a web page using perl?

Tags: perl, http

I'm new to perl. Now I need to write a perl program to download web pages from a web site periodically. I see some useful methods to establish network connections and get content, but I don't know which is better. Can anybody recommend some libraries to download web pages with sample codes, or tutorial sites? I hope it's simple to start with, like the pseudo codes:

use library;

open a connection;
get the content;
process if success or handle error.

And it's better to have cookie support.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend libcurl. It's simple and has full functionality to handle almost everything about http including cookie support. And it has many different language bindings, so it's easy for you to turn to other languages. Using cpan to search for perl's binding. The official website is http://curl.haxx.se

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little bit familiar with C, so libcurl might be my choice.

Answer (score 5):

Check the [LWP module](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP.pm). The documentation includes examples.